# Disable Browser Zooming

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I want to disable zooming in my website and use this code on the hade tag :

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

but it dosent work. i need a way that users cant zoom in or zoom out.

Comment: Are you talking about browsers for Android/iOS/et al or common desktop operating systems?

Answer (score 0):

Try user-scalable=0 instead of no

```
<head>
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, depends of what you want. Your code seems right for mobile app.
But, AFAIK, it's impossible to do the same thing in browsers (like Firefox, IE...). You can always zoom in / zoom out.

viewport is not for web-browser but mobile. It's like disable right click or image download : not a good practice ;)